# better way to write "in Apple's iMac's common MacOS"

Tags: word-choice

I was looking at a better way to write the following while emphasizing Apple in the beginning. But it seems like too many possessive s usages.

What could be a substitute?

> "The software that runs on Apple's iMac's commonly used MacOS"

Comment: Note maybe you should use _OS X_, unless of course you mean a pre-OS X operating system.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to reduce the number of apostrophe S's in your sentence is to 1) attach the definite article to *Apple*, and 2) dispense with the apostrophe S that follows it:

> The software that runs on the Apple iMac's commonly-used MacOS [is....]

Comment: Why is adding "the" needed? "The software that runs on Apple iMac's commonly-used MacOS" seems correct.

Comment: @JoeBlack - I would ask you why you think that the "the" is *not* needed here. It is standard usage to precede a proper noun with the definite article when describing its characteristics. For instance, you would say: "The acceleration from **the Ford Fiesta's** 957 cc engine is modest at best". You would *not* say:  "The acceleration from **Ford Fiesta's** 957 cc engine is modest at best".

Comment: I am not sure if the rules regarding definite articles are so clear cut. You can have no definite article before a proper noun. For example, you'd say "you visited India" not "you visited the India." Also, "X is working at Apple" not "X is working at the Apple." I don't you'd use "the" before the company names.

Comment: @JoeBlack - Yes, I was slightly careless in making an assertion that was more sweeping than I intended it to be (I don't use "the" before company names either when referring solely to the company rather than to one of its products). *However,* I patterned my example on the Apple sentence in order to make it fully comparable. I stand by the validity of that example and the accuracy of my description regarding standard usage of the definite article in similar cases.

Comment: The definiteness in the use of definite article in your example is associated not with Ford but with "957 cc engine," which is presumably something that's been mentioned to the reader or is unique. If you example said "acceleration from Ford Fiesta's new model XXL" then it would be correct usage and use of "the" in this case would be incorrect. The example with MacOS is the same.

Comment: @JoeBlack - In my example, "957 cc engine" is analagous to "iMac" in the parallel sentence. "The acceleration from Ford Fiesta's new model XXL..." implies that the new model XXL has been manufactured by the entity **Ford Fiesta,** which is not the case: the manufacturer is *Ford,* not *Ford Fiesta*. The right way to word your version would be something like "The acceleration from Ford's latest version of the Fiesta, the XXL..." However, I think we would both agree that "The acceleration from Ford's new Fiesta..." works without placing "the" in front of *Ford*.